# CQWP Group by Content Type

Tags: 2013, content-type, content-query-web-part, grouping

Is there a way to group by content type in Content Query Web Parts (CQWP)? I have created a list with 4 content types. We need to display the items in a CQWP but grouped by content type. I have tried manipulating an exported CQWP, but can't accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I modified the CQWP Snippet in my page layout display template.

**In the CQWP Snippet change the following:**

> GroupBy="Author" GroupByFieldType="User" SortBy="Posted"
>   SortByFieldType="DateTime" SortByDirection="Desc"

**To:**

> GroupBy="ContentType" GroupByFieldType="Text" SortBy="ContentType"
>   SortByFieldType="Text" SortByDirection="Asc"`